# Convert a javascript list to dictionary

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a javascript list to a dictionary with a specified key. 
I'm using the following code:

```js
let list = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'fish']

list = list.map(x => {
  return ({ animal: x });
})
 
console.log(list);
```

> Of course this doesn't work. 
>   Edit: It actually does

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "animal": "cat"
  },
  {
    "animal": "rabbit"
  },
  {
    "animal": "fish"
  }
]
```

Edit:

**let** and **list=list** was in fact a typo in the question - it is correct in my real code. I didnt test this snippet as I didnt think it worked. I also then confused myself and did type the expected result wrong. My code is more complex and it didn't make sense to post it all. As works, I think my bug must be elsewhere. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, just to get that right, you want an object with three times the distinct property `animal`?

Comment: Your expected result makes no sense.  What you're getting should be `[{animal: 'cat'}, {animal: 'rabbit'}, {animal: 'fish'}]`.

Comment: What kind of app you're making? Is it a Node.JS or raw JS that must render in the browser?

Comment: A dictionary by definition should have UNIQUE keys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Of course this doesn't work.

It does (if we fix the typo in `Let` and we assume you wanted an array of three objects), you're just not using the result:

```js
    let list = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'fish']

//  vvvvvvv
    list = list.map(x => {
      return({animal: x});
    });
    console.log(list);
```

Or more briefly with a concise arrow function:

```js
let list = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'fish']

list = list.map(x => ({animal: x}));
console.log(list);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this is what he's trying to do though. He seems to want a Map with 3 identical keys; inside a list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Saw Rocket Hazmat's comment. I'm inclined until the OP comes back to assume that's a typo in the question. I could be wrong, though, hopefully they'll tell us.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: That "expected result" is *impossible* and probably just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make an asside to @T.J. Crowder's answer: Ecma Script 6 (ES6) could not render in old browsers and Internet Explorer *(just arrow functions `=>`)* you could use code below instead:

```js
var list = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'fish']

list = list.map(function(x) {
  return ({
    animal: x
  });
});

console.log(list);
```

If you'll keep the original list, you could use code below:

```js
var list = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'fish']

var result = list.map(function(x) {
  return ({
    animal: x
  });
});

console.log(list);
console.log(result);
```

Typical things in ES6 are:

- `let` and `const` keywords | check: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let)
- Arrow functions (`=>`) | check: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)